# Cant make my site available to the internet

Tags: apache2

Hi I'm using Ubuntu as server OS for my webhosting but I'm having problem redirecting my domainname to my server.

Here are my `/etc/hosts` file and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite` file.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   www.lowkey.se

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

sites-available/file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.lowkey.se

    DocumentRoot /var/www/doost/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/doost/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And a screenshot from my domain name provider:

[image]

The site has been enabled in Ubuntu. 
I've restarted apache2 and the folder `/var/www/doost/` is there. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1) your mysite file needs this 1st line

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
```

2) Enable your site by running in terminal:

```
    sudo a2ensite mysite
```

3) The procedure to publish a site to Internet needs:

- a **web** (not intranet) **ip** (213.xxx.xxx.xxx) which you have to **attach** from your router, to your Ubuntu server **intranet (fake) static ip** (192.168.xxx.xxx). This must be done from the router panel.
- set your Ubuntu server **intranet (fake) static ip** (192.168.xxx.xxx) in /etc/hosts file (add this line)

  192.168.xxx.xxx www.lowkey.se
- Tell your **domain provider** of lowkey.se to **turn lowkey.se hearing in the router web ip  (213.xxx.xxx.xxx)**

After some hours you can see www.lowkey.se through Internet.